# AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application I am disgusted

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

Hey Guys after publish to Azure I get the following error when I want to login.
I checked the URL in my Code and the App Registration --> It's the same...

> When i run with Azure domain: (I already created a new registered app)

We're unable to complete your request
unauthorized_client:
The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.

> When I run **localhost** login appears and I logging in it redirects
> me to this:

**The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.**

AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: 'ace44f89-fa01-41a3-8d0c-f0835adb1065'.

## Troubleshooting details:

---

Request Id: e9199aae-5431-4ca5-ae1e-ad2ab78f0a00
Correlation Id: cc29341a-f2bd-4b2b-a968-474c8203c493
Timestamp: 2021-04-13T07:32:21Z

Message: AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: 'ace44f89-fa01-41a3-8d0c-f0835adb1065'.

Comment: With this error, you can always check the current URL in the browser address bar. It should contain a "redirect_uri" query parameter, that is what your app is trying to use. That is not matching with what is configured.

Comment: @juunas the redirect_uri in the browser looks like: redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fnotentool20210315154131.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Fmicrosoftaccount%2

Comment: I'm guessing there is an F missing from the end and the URL decoded version is "https://notentool20210315154131.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/microsoftaccount/". This is what should be in the reply URLs.

Comment: As  @juunas said, just decode it and paste it into Azure.

Comment: If the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @juunas i copied the url of you and pasted into azure but again after the publish i get the same error (The reply URL specified request does not match the reply URLs...) 

https://login.microsoftonline.com/a6bbab92-053e-490b-bd7e-5cd03763b746/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fnotentool20210315154131.azurewebsites.net%2f.auth%2flogin%2faad%2fcallback&client_id=ace44f89-fa01-41a3-8d0c-f0835adb1065 THIS is the link (shortened) which I get displayed on the Login page..

Comment: @Noah  Can you provide me with the complete url ?  let me decode it for you.

Comment: This is the url, I need you to copy it to me in full.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY87B.jpg

Comment: https://login.microsoftonline.com/a6bbab92-053e-490b-bd7e-5cd03763b746/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fnotentool20210315154131.azurewebsites.net%2f.auth%2flogin%2faad%2fcallback&client_id=ace44f89-fa01-41a3-8d0c-f0835adb1065&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=cabf41aad4c04d20b46a1a5b7f0ccc95_20210420090723&state=redir%3d%252F&sso_nonce=AwABAAAAAAACAOz_BAD0_4g3my1Z-FxDK5shqbGvQBe1pj-9-hbUeNtgmvED9R3zcNDTgZjgrO1o9iRMVpcuI9YCD6c1_mJep6wgJg28LyQgAA&client-request-id=cb01355b-2891-4c31-8aec-66839da51ecb&mscrid=cb01355b-2891-4c31-8aec-66839

Comment: @CarlZhao The link is too lang put this at the end: da51ecb

Comment: @Noah   try this : `https://notentool20210315154131.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback`.

Comment: @CarlZhao still not working ;(

Comment: @Noah  Please provide a screenshot of your redirect_uri configured in Azure.

Comment: @CarlZhao https://ibb.co/DWBT3t8

Comment: @Noah  What happens if  use this url to get the id token? I just tested it without errors.  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={client id}
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=https://notentool20210315154131.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
&response_mode=form_post
&scope=openid profile email
&state=12345
&nonce=678910`

Comment: see:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/emhcV.png

Comment: @CarlZhao After the login it says "bad request" and at the top in the  search bar is the following link: https://notentool20210315154131.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback

Answer (score 0):

> The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers.

This error means you are using a Microsoft Account to login your client app, but it is not enabled for that.

To change the setting for an existing AD App, navigate to the **Manifest** blade of it in the portal, find the [signInAudience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#signinaudience-attribute) attribute, set it with `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount` or `PersonalMicrosoftAccount`.

[image]

> AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the
> reply URLs configured for the application

When you visit the application url , you will be redirected to the login page. Decode the authorization request url, you will find `redirect_url`, copy the value of `redirect_url` and paste it into the azure portal, and try again.

[image]

Comment: To decode the URL, one way is to use the browser console + `decodeURIComponent("encoded-uri-here")`.

Comment: I did it, but still getting the same error... But I found something in my Manifest of the Registered App, is this important? Do I have to change this:

"requiredResourceAccess": [
  {
   "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
   "resourceAccess": [
    {
     "id": "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
     "type": "Scope"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]

Comment: @Noah   This is just the MS graph api permission granted by you to the application, this does not need to be changed.